# Digital ocean droplet running rails application getting compromised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I was running my rails application on a digital ocean droplet with Ubuntu 14.04. Within days of launch, my droplet got hacked. I had taken care of the following things while setting up the droplet. But still the security had been compromised.

1) No root password. I had set up the root user with ssh key
2) The rails application is hosted in a private repo. So not even the IP of the machine was exposed.
3) Changed the default port of rails app.

I know the above configurations are basic but it usually gets the job done for me.

I setup a new droplet after the droplet was compromised. Again, within days, the new droplet was also compromised. So there is definitely a security hole in my setup.

To give a background about the rails application, it is an app that uses Twilio voice APIs , MySQL as the DB, unicorn as the app server, sidekiq and redis for background processing.

I still have console access to the latest compromised droplet. While looking for clues in the compromised droplet and noticed some rogue ssh key entries in authorized_keys file. I could not find anything else out of the ordinary or how the authorized_keys file got new entries.

How should I be debugging this problem ?

Comment: The issue could be in your app, any of the gems of your app, rails itself or any other software component that you are exposing to the internet. I would check Rails, unicorn and all the gems you have in your app to see if there are reported security holes in the CVE database or their websites.

Answer (score 0):

The security hole existed in redis setup. The below article explains in detail.
http://antirez.com/news/96

Long story short, redis setup out of the box exposes 6379 port to the internet.